# ProtectedRoutes function. How to call redux useSelector()

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

My current `AppRoutes` looks like this.

```
<Switch>
    <ProtectedRoute
        exact
        path="/"
        component={Home}
    />
    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
</Switch>
```

I have made a ProtectedRoute function

```
const { isAuthenticated, isAuthenticating } = useSelector(state => state.auth)

const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (    
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        isVerifying ? (
          <Loading />
        ) : isLoggedIn ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: props.location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
```

Before I used to have it within `AppRoutes` but I decided to move in my `ProtectedRoute` function to make it look cleaner and a single responsibility instead of passing it down as props.

But I get the following error:

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a
>   function component.

I get the error because I have declared it outside of the function and was wondering where I would need to place it and also is there a better approach to handle ProtectedRoutes?

Comment: Could you give precision about where `isAuthenticated, isAuthenticating` are used ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you keep it inside your `ProtectedRoute` component ?

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const { isAuthenticated, isAuthenticating } = useSelector(state => state.auth)
  return (    
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        isVerifying ? (
          <Loading />
        ) : isLoggedIn ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: props.location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know or have any feedback on a better way to handle protectedroutes?

Comment: Actually I use quite the same way for my protected routes in my Reactjs applications. If this solution worked for you please consider upvoting and accepting as answer, thanks !